# how many points inside rectangle so distance is $0<d\leq \sqrt{2}$.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, pigeonhole-principle

Given a rectangle with dimensions $m$ inches and $n$ inches. How many points inside that rectangle have to be chosen to make sure that two of them have distance $d$ with $0 < d \leq \sqrt{2}$?

Here is my attempt: We want to divide the rectangle into "whole" unit squares each of length 1 and the remaining will be rectangles. We know we have $a = \lfloor m \rfloor \cdot \lfloor n \rfloor$ many unit squares and (EDIT:2) $b = \lceil m -\lfloor m\rfloor\rceil \cdot \lfloor n \rfloor + \lceil n -\lfloor n\rfloor\rceil \cdot \lfloor m \rfloor + \lceil m -\lfloor m\rfloor\rceil\cdot \lceil n -\lfloor n\rfloor\rceil$ many rectangles. (EDIT:1) Then choose $a + b + 1$ many points.

Feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to get an asymptotic solution by looking at optimal 2d circular packing but I expect the exact solution is probably a really big complicated formula.

Comment: @DanielV, I believe so. I am just looking for a succinct answer/hint considering this is a (relatively) easy pigeonhole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m$ and $n$ integers, we need $mn+1$ points to have at least one unit square with at least two points in it

For non-integers $m$ and $n$ we need $ (\lfloor {m} \rfloor+1)(\lfloor {n}\rfloor +1)+1 $ points to cover the unit squares and the rectangles.

For $m$ integer and $n$ non-integer, we need $ (m)(\lfloor {n} \rfloor+1)+1$
Similarly for $m$ non-integer and $n$ integer  we need $ (n)(\lfloor {m} \rfloor+1)+1$ points.

Comment: I agree. I made a typo in my Answer. Please see fix. I believe the cases you mentioned are all contained within my answer. But do please let me know if you agree or not.

Comment: I do like your answer as opposed to my nested ceil/floor functions answer due to yours being more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Comment: after doing example, I realized an error in what I had. Please take a look if you would like.